# Limit the precision on std::cout of default values in boost::options_description

Tags: c++, precision, cout, boost-program-options

When I construct a boost::options_description instance like

```
options.add_options()
  ("double_val", value(&config.my_double)->default_value(0.2), "it's a double");
```

and later want to have the automated output of the options that are available for my program, and put

```
std::cout << options << std::endl;
```

the default value 0.2 is shown with way too high precision, which effectively clutters my output when I have long variable names:

```
--double_val (=0.20000000000000001) it's a double
```

unfortunately, a prior call to std::cout.precision did not help:

```
cout.precision(5);
std::cout << options << std::endl;
```

this leads still to the same output :/

Do you have any ideas on how to limit the display of the default value to less positions?

Best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 11):

From `boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp`:

```
    /** Specifies default value, which will be used
        if none is explicitly specified. The type 'T' should
        provide operator<< for ostream.
    */
    typed_value* default_value(const T& v)
    {
        m_default_value = boost::any(v);
        m_default_value_as_text = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(v);
        return this;
    }

    /** Specifies default value, which will be used
        if none is explicitly specified. Unlike the above overload,
        the type 'T' need not provide operator<< for ostream,
        but textual representation of default value must be provided
        by the user.
    */
    typed_value* default_value(const T& v, const std::string& textual)
    {
        m_default_value = boost::any(v);
        m_default_value_as_text = textual;
        return this;
    }
```

So the implementation is dead simple (never a sure thing with Boost!).  Trying to reconfigure your ostream to make the formatting come out as you want won't work, because the default value just gets converted to a string in a standalone `ostringstream` (inside `lexical_cast`).

So a simple workaround is to add your desired string representation as a second argument to `default_value`.  Then you can make it print however you want (including not at all, if you pass an empty string).  Like so:

```
value(&config.my_double)->default_value(0.2, "0.2")
```

The more "enterprisey" way to accomplish the same thing would be to implement your own type which would wrap `double`, be used for `config.my_double`, and provide construction from and coercion to `double`, and your very own `ostream& operator<<` with exactly the formatting you desire.  I don't suggest this approach, however, unless you're writing a library that demands generality.

From the Boost Lexical Cast notes:

> The previous version of lexical_cast
>   used the default stream precision for
>   reading and writing floating-point
>   numbers. For numerics that have a
>   corresponding specialization of
>   std::numeric_limits, the current
>   version now chooses a precision to
>   match.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to quote by hand:

```
#define QUOTE(x) #x
#define stringize(x) QUOTE(x)

#define MY_DOUBLE_DEFAULT 0.2

value(&config.my_double)->default_value(MY_DOUBLE_DEFAULT, stringize(MY_DOUBLE_DEFAULT))
```